# I tell fsck to fix USB stick, it says "Leaving file system unchanged."

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, fedora

So I run fsck, and it reports

```
FATs differ but appear to be intact. Use which FAT ?
1) Use first FAT
2) Use second FAT
```

Choosing either one gives a long list of errors like

```
Cluster 1471730 out of range (164977891 > 1980013). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 1471732 out of range (252397720 > 1980013). Setting to EOF.
Cluster 1471734 out of range (18601458 > 1980013). Setting to EOF.
```

Then it says,

```
Reclaimed 93886 unused clusters (769114112 bytes).
Free cluster summary wrong (1034047 vs. really 1221912)
1) Correct
2) Don't correct
```

If I choose (1), it just exits with no action:

```
Leaving file system unchanged.
/dev/sdb1: 53 files, 758100/1980012 clusters
```

So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 23):

After unmounting the USB volume, you'll want to use fsck with the '-w' switch which forces fsck to immediately write changes. Note that '-w' requires '-a' (auto mode) or '-r' (interactive mode).

Comment: I really miss ``-w`` option! +1

Answer (score 9):

man fsck.vfat says:

> Note: If -a and -r are absent, the filesystem is only checked, but not repaired.

So, to have it actually write your changes use either -a or -r. The -w option modifies the behaviour of those two.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the fsck man page.
Maybe try -r option or leave the -n if you used it.

Another possibility is that the partition is completely full. Check this.

By the way, it would be very helpful to post the exactly command that you used.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to passing -w -r like user130302 said, I had to run fsck.vfat with the partition *mounted* so that fsck would be able to write the found clusters (into FSCK000n.REC files).

Comment: Wow, this goes against everything I would have thought about fsck, but doing this on my sd card kept prompting me to correct an issue with free cluster size. Despite choosing to correct, it did the same upon subsequent checks. Mounting caught a dirty bit in addition to cluster issue and fixed both (finally checks clean now).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I eventually got it to work just by using the dosfsck command directly rather than using fsck (which is just a wrapper for all of the various fsck tools).  I guess when fsck calls dosfsck it adds some options which cause it to fail to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, inspired of the answer from user258400 i used
directly:

```
fsck.fat -r /dev/sde1
```

instead of:

```
fsck -r /dev/sde1
```

which did the trick